# OCMock automatically use mocked instance in code under test?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am new in [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/reference/).

I use `dispatch_once()` created a singleton class `MyManager` :

```
@implementation MyManager

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

I have a method in `School` class which uses the above singleton:

```
@implementation School
...
- (void) createLecture {
  MyManager *mgr = [MyManager sharedInstance];
  [mgr checkLectures];
  ...
}
@end
```

Now, I want to unit test this method, I use a partial mock of MyManager:

```
- (void) testCreateLecture {
  // create a partially mocked instance of MyManager
  id partialMockMgr = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[MyManager sharedInstance]];

  // run method to test
  [schoolToTest createLecture];
  ...
}
```

I noticed that with OCMock, after I created the partial mock of my singleton `MyManager` instance, when run my method under test, it **automatically** use the partially mocked instance.

This is a bit weird to me, since in my test case above, I only created the partial mock of `MyManager` instance without injecting it to `MyManager` class,

how does OCMock automatically force the code under test use this mocked instance when `[MyManager sharedInstance]` is called in the code under test ? Could someone explain to me this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`partialMockForObject` mocks the object you are passing to it.

In this case you are mocking the singleton (shared) object. You don't have to inject anything because `sharedInstance` is always returning the same object, now mocked. It is still the same reference.

Imagine partial mocking as a simple mutation of the passed object, it doesn't create a new instance so you don't have to inject it in this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Partial Mocks are pretty cool. Behind the scenes, OCMock subclasses the class you are mocking, and any method that you stub is updated in the partial mock subclass. So all references to your mocked class will now default to the subclass (mocked implementation) instead of the superclass (your implementation). There's a good [explanation in the reference](http://ocmock.org/reference/#partial-mocks) on this as well.

Comment: Even though I accepted @Sulthan 's answer,  the information in your answer is also very important to me! thanks!